# Use facebook tracking pixel for registration success that does not redirect to success page

Tags: facebook, event-tracking

How do I set a facebook pixel event to track registration completion when my registration form completion redirects to my index page not to a registration success page?

Should I use a standard event or a custom event to achieve this, or, do I have to create an intermediate page that the registration form directs to and then redirects to index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire the Facebook Pixel event when the user clicks on the form submit with 'click' event listener. Standard versus Custom events is a separate issue, but I suggest sticking with Standard events where you can.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/

Comment: What about the form not validating after the click? If the user enters invalid details and clicks the submit button, I will be recording the user as registered when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen, you provided too few information.

1. Richy is right that in your case if you can't control where your user lands after submitting the form you should use onClick event to send a pixel event. You can easily validate the form in the code of the onClick event and send it when you're sure data is according to your expectations. You can even do additional requests to your back-end to check the data.
2. If you can change how your web-site work you can make a landing page where you'd fire an event if all the processing went right.
3. If you can also easily do it on your index page by loading it with some parameter in the URL that indicates it is visited after the form was submitted. There you can have a simple JS code snipped with condition in it to fire a pixel event if URL parameter is present or do it with Google Tag manager which is even simpler.

There are a couple of good standard events you can use like Subscribe or Submit Application, review them here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference#standard-events

You have countless options depending on what level of changes you can do to the site, you coding skills, CMS you use and precision you need.